# Issue with Asymptote Execution in LaTeX: "failed to create directory /.asy."

Tags: latex, pdflatex, miktex, asymptote

Note: I initially asked this question on TeX Stack Exchange, but unfortunately, I did not receive a response. I am reposting it here to get help from a broader community.

Here is the link to the original post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/700578/asymptote-code-generates-asy-files-but-asymptote-execution-fails

This question further explores an issue that was previously addressed in one of my earlier inquiries on TeX.SE:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/700514/asymptote-error-missing-pdf-file-during-compilation

I am encountering a peculiar issue when working with my LaTeX document that includes Asymptote code. The LaTeX compilation appears to generate the necessary `.asy` files, but when I attempt to execute Asymptote separately on these files, I encounter difficulties.

Here's the setup and the steps I have taken:

- I am using a Windows operating system.
- I have successfully installed LaTeX, Asymptote, and Ghostscript, and have verified that all three are included in my system's PATH.
- I use the -shell-escape option when compiling my LaTeX document.

The LaTeX compilation log suggests that the Asymptote code is being executed correctly, as I observe the generation of a PDF file `(asymptote-latex-1.pdf)`. However, when I try to run Asymptote manually on the generated `.asy` files, it does not work.

I have tried using the following commands to run Asymptote:

1. `asy "C:\Users\twill\OneDrive\Desktop\ASYMPTOTE\output-directory\asymptote-latex-1.asy"`
2. `asy C:\Users\twill\asymptote-latex-*.asy`

Despite this, I encounter issues, and Asymptote does not seem to process the files correctly. The specific error message I am facing is: `failed to create directory /.asy.`. The log of the LaTeX compilation does not provide any error messages related to Asymptote.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue where the LaTeX compilation generates `.asy` files, but Asymptote execution on these files fails? I would greatly appreciate any insights, troubleshooting steps, or solutions to ensure that the Asymptote code processes the `.asy` files correctly.

Thank you for your assistance.

MWE: (Credit: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/537967/filename-1-pdf-not-found-asymptote)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
size(200);
pen[] p={red,green,blue,magenta};
path g=(0,0){dir(45)}..(1,0)..(1,1)..(0,1)..cycle;
tensorshade(g,p);
dot(g);
\end{asy}
\end{document}
```

log:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (MiKTeX 23.5) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.8.22)  6 NOV 2023 10:25
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**C:/Users/twill/OneDrive/Desktop/ASYMPTOTE/asymptote-latex.tex
(C:/Users/twill/OneDrive/Desktop/ASYMPTOTE/asymptote-latex.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-08-11>
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@section=\count186
\c@subsection=\count187
\c@subsubsection=\count188
\c@paragraph=\count189
\c@subparagraph=\count190
\c@figure=\count191
\c@table=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen140
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks17
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics\trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-cfg\graphics.c
fg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 107.

(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/graphics-def\pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2022/09/22 v1.2b Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen141
\Gin@req@width=\dimen142
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/asymptote\asymptote.sty
Package: asymptote 2021/12/29 v1.37 Asymptote style file for LaTeX
(asymptote-latex.pre)
\ASYbox=\box51
\ASYdimen=\dimen143
\c@asy=\count193
\AsyStream=\write3
\AsyPreStream=\write4

(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2022/04/13 v1.1d Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2019/10/25 v3.4 ifpdf legacy package. Use iftex instead.

(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
))
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/iftex\ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2019/10/25 v0.7 ifxetex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/catchfile\catchfile.s
ty
Package: catchfile 2019/12/09 v1.8 Catch the contents of a file (HO)

(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/infwarerr\infwarerr.s
ty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/ltxcmds\ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/generic/etexcmds\etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
))
\openout4 = `asymptote-latex.pre'.

)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdf
tex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2023-04-19 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count194
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box52
) (asymptote-latex.aux)
\openout1 = `asymptote-latex.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.

(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/context/base/mkii\supp-pdf.mk
ii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count195
\scratchdimen=\dimen144
\scratchbox=\box53
\nofMPsegments=\count196
\nofMParguments=\count197
\everyMPshowfont=\toks18
\MPscratchCnt=\count198
\MPscratchDim=\dimen145
\MPnumerator=\count199
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count266
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks19
)
(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg\epstopdf-b
ase.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.

(C:\Users\twill\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/00miktex\epstopdf-sys.c
fg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2021/03/18 v2.0 Configuration of epstopdf for MiKTeX
))
\openout3 = `asymptote-latex-1.asy'.

<asymptote-latex-1.pdf, id=1, 200.75pt x 131.06967pt>
File: asymptote-latex-1.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use asymptote-latex-1.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: asymptote-latex-1.pdf  used on input line 11.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 200.7495pt x 131.06934pt.
 [1

{C:/Users/twill/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map} <./asymptote-
latex-1.pdf>] (asymptote-latex.aux)
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-08-11>
 ***********
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1800 strings out of 475503
 31543 string characters out of 5761834
 1916248 words of memory out of 12000000
 23078 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 558069 words of font info for 36 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 62i,5n,65p,256b,139s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
<C:/Users/twill/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/
cmr10.pfb>
Output written on asymptote-latex.pdf (1 page, 9798 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 13 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 6 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on that a bit please - I'm still new to a lot of computer terminology.  1. By pdf reader, do you mean the pdflatex command or adobe acrobat or something else? 2. Are you suggesting that move the .asy files to another directory such as the desktop (or away from the desktop)? Pardon my lack of understanding, I'm still new to computers.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Let me transfer my LaTeX files to one folder and specify an output directory in that folder for the log and .asy files etc., and get back to you on this. Thanks again!

Comment: Let me do some research to specify the output directory for my LaTeX files to be in one folder. Give me like 30 minutes to get this in order. Thanks by the way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255886/discussion-between-pseudonym123-and-k-j).

Comment: Really? The reason I thought it involved ghostscript was because of all the renaming of the ghostscript files. How is this not a gs issue? Like, I get its a modified GS, but still...

Comment: I'll be honest, I don't completely understand how this isn't a GS issue. But I'll trust your better judgement and remove the tag

Comment: Thank you for bringing this up, always happy to improve my content

Answer (score 1):

With help from a professor at my university, the issue has been resolved!

Here are the steps I took (for future self reference and for others struggling with the same thing).

Step 1: Uninstall ghostscript and miktex

Step 2: install miktex and the latest ghostscript.

Step 3: global search for mgs and change its same to something else (I used mgstemp)

Step 4: global search for gswin64.exe and change its name to mgs

Step 5: any time you update MikTeX, it will create a new mgs file (in the MikTex Directory!!!!!!). You need to change this to another name every time.

Step 6: The commands `pdflatex test` then `asy test-1.asy` then `pdflatex test` will produce your document!

Comment: I have yet to try it on a more complex graph, so I'll cross that bridge if I have to.